# How can I use auto increment in my composite unique key in Django?

Tags: python, mysql, django, database, sqlite

I have a model class like this:

```
class TestModel(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('prefix', 'number')

    prefix = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    number = models.IntegerField()
```

prefix and number together form a natural key for my model, but I don't particularly care what the number is. Thus, auto increment (not per-prefix) would be fine. I don't want to have to specify the number, but I want to be able to (e.g. because there are existing prefix+number pairs that need to put into this system).

For eaxmple, most times I'd just want to use auto increment:

```
'the_prefix', 1
'the_prefix', 2
```

However, I might want to use particular (prefix, number) combination in a few cases, such as (prefix, number) pairs from a legacy system:

```
'manually', 2  # number is not unique alone...
'manually', 4  # ... or sequential
```

---

As I understand it,

- only Single-column PKs are supported, so I can't use prefix+number as a composite PK directly;
- only AutoField is auto-incrementing, and there can be only one AutoField per model (and it must be the PK), so I can't have both id & number auto incremented; and
- instead making prefix+id unique together makes no sense, as id is already unique on its own.

Is there a way to achieve this (or is one of my statements wrong)? If there is a database-agnostic solution, that would of course be preferred, but otherwise, SQLite (development) and MySQL (production) are most important to me personally.

Workarounds are also welcome - I'm trying to use the PK as "default" for number, but

- keeping number blank to specify the default defeats the unique constraint, and
- to copy the id, one needs to save the object without a number first. I struggle to implement this in a way that seems reliable and transparent to the user